# Error 404 de la nada en Wordpress // Fallo al publicar. La respuesta no es una respuesta JSON válida

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un wordpress en un ambiente local.
De un momento a otro, Wordpress dejó de funcionar.
Aparecieron estos errores, el 404 en la página y el de JSON al actualizar algo.

Ahora mismo, no puedo hacer nada, ni crear páginas nuevas, ni editarlas.
Alguna idea de por que sucede esto?

He intentado lo siguiente:

1. Quitar/desactivar Gunterberg : Al parecer da problemas, asi que lo quite, pero no funciona.
2. Desactivar todos los plugins y actualizar permalinks. Sin resultado alguno.
3. Borrar y crear páginas de nuevo, sin resultado.

---

**UPDATE#1**
Creía haber encontrado una solución, pero fue temporal.
Las páginas siguen sin funcionar y sin poder crearse/editarse.

Comment: Imagino que tendrías mejores respuestas si fueses a preguntar a un sitio específico de wordpress? Un vistazo rápido en google da varios resultados interesantes... aquí sin código poco vamos a poder ayudarte

Comment: He revisado al menos 20 páginas dedicadas, ninguna tiene solución a dicho problema. Si alguien tiene información, lo ideal es buscarla. Codigo, ninguno, es una falla de wordpress que tenga que ver con otra cosa, llevo solo 2 días diseñando la página y de la nada, sin tocar codigo, se rompe.

Comment: Si es un fallo de wordpress, ir a preguntar a una comunidad especializada en wordpress te podría ser de muchísima más ayuda que preguntar aquí. No te lo digo por mal, es simplemente que estás preguntando en una comunidad donde un par de personas con suerte trabajarán de normal con wordpress, mientras que en los foros de soporte de WP tendrás cientos.

Comment: Que errores te da, código de error, en que partes específicamente o al realizar una acción especifica? lastimosamente con tan poca información es imposible saber que sucede en tu sitio

Comment: Yo podría aconsejarte que descargues tu sitio a un ambiente local, y pruebes no solo desactivando sino borrando los plugins, o hasta cambiando el tema con el que trabajas, solo cuida bien de tu base de datos y crea dos o tres respaldos. Estoy de acuerdo en que dejes màs detalle sobre el problema.

Comment: @Benito-B si benito si, no he ido a preguntar, gracias por entender el comentario que te puse.

Comment: @JefferzonBol esa es la unica info que tengo, por que paso de la nada, nisiquiera estaba tocando codigo, estaba cambiando estilos, cuando todo se fue a la B

Comment: @Ana Es un ambiente local, perdon por no especificar eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solución finalmente encontrada.
Mayormente estos problemas ocurren por el uso de plugins,
Aunque en mi caso dudo que fuese eso, no lo descarto.

Ocurre que para que a Wordpress se le desaparezcan las páginas de la nada
Tienen que haber pasado algunas cosas, generalmente son 3:

- Problemas con el caché
- Problemas con el DNS
- Problemas de compatibilidad

Acá en la tercera opción, es donde caerían los plugins, quienes, por opción, 
modifican las reglas o los enlaces permanentes de las páginas, sin actualizarlas en la base de datos.

### SOLUCION

Ir a la `pestaña Opciones > Enlaces Permanentes` y cambiar las opciones.
Si tenias la opción "plano" marcada, poner alguna otra
Además de guardar entre cambios.
En mi caso, estaba en "nombre de la entrada", lo cambie a "plano", guardé.